# How to check size of related records without using controller

Tags: visualforce

I have a simple requirement in which I have used standard Controller Account in VF like this -

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
  <apex:pageBlock >
   <apex:relatedList list="Contact">
        <apex:facet name="header">Titles can be overriden with facets</apex:facet>
    </apex:relatedList>
  </apex:pageBlock> 
</apex:page> <br />
```

Here I want to check whether the Account has related contacts or not without using controller that is I want to evaluate this logic at page level  itself . But if try to use something like this - `{!Account.Contacts.size}`, I get

> error message Invalid field 'size' for SObject 'Contact'.

I even tried with following VF functions - ISBLANK and IF for checking whether its blank or null respectively but no help. Both returns false even if there is no related contact records. Any suggestions? 
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
  <apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:variable var="j" value="{!0}"/>
    <apex:repeat var="i" value="{!Account.Contacts}">
      <apex:variable var="j" value="{!j+1}"/>{!j}
    </apex:repeat>
    <script>
      alert('{!j}');
    </script>
    <apex:relatedList list="Contacts">
      <apex:facet name="header">Titles can be overriden with facets</apex:facet>
    </apex:relatedList>
  </apex:pageBlock> 
</apex:page>
```

Use `<apex:variable>` and `<apex:repeat>` for calculate

---

**Edit** -----

```
<script>
   var countSize = 0;

   <apex:repeat var="i" value="{!Account.Contacts}">
       countSize+=1;
   </apex:repeat>

   alert(countSize);
</script>
```

Comment: Yes I have used that. But was thinking of some better alternative if exist

Comment: @MonalisaDas @Ratan Normally you can just use `.size` to get a number of the elements in the child relationship. Like `{!obj.relation__r.size}` But in this case it is not working :(

Comment: @mast0r Aggree I found it is difficult with `.size` The only way I found this. Let see if any one have better option

Comment: @Ratan I have just added rows="1" attribute to apex repeat so that it doesn't need to iterate over the whole long list rows.

Comment: If you add rows="1" then it will count only one record.

Comment: @Ratan I just need to check whether it has related records or not,not number of related records